# Energy Positivity of Classical QED Field Theory in Presence of Sources

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, field-theory, dirac-equation, classical-field-theory

It's well known that the classical electromagnetic field has positive definite energy, simply because:
$$\mathcal{H}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0\vec{E}^2+\frac{1}{2\mu_0}\vec{B}^2.$$
However, this result only applies in the case of the free electromagnetic field. Is there a positive energy condition when considering a configuration consisting of source currents and charges? I would need a Lagrangian/Hamiltonian which includes the Lorentz force on the source current as well, but as far as I know there is only the Lagrangian for a single point particle in an electromagnetic field stated in literature, and not for a general current density $\vec{J}$.

However, we may examine QED as a classical field theory, which already has the sources included as the Dirac field. Here we find terms which may contribute negatively:
$$H=\int d^{3} x\left[\frac{1}{2} \vec{A}^{2}+\frac{1}{2} \vec{B}^{2}+\bar{\psi}\left(-i \gamma^{i} \partial_{i}+m\right) \psi-e \vec{j} \cdot \vec{A}+\frac{e^{2}}{2} \int d^{3} x^{\prime} \frac{j^{0}(\vec{x}) j^{0}\left(\vec{x}^{\prime}\right)}{4 \pi\left|\vec{x}-\vec{x}^{\prime}\right|}\right]$$
namely the $-e \vec{j} \cdot \vec{A}$ term could be made arbitrarily large in either sign. Is there a **Classical** constraint on the Hamiltonian density? This is similar to a question I already asked, but here the emphasis is completely different. Just to clarify, my question is: **in the presence of sources**: charges and currents, and not just the free field contribution, does Classical Electromagnetism, or **QED **as a Classical Field Theory**** exhibit the locally positive energy density condition?

Comment: I am referring to demoting the Hamiltonian from an operator to a c-number. I am trying to capture the corresponding classical dynamics as if I was doing reverse canonical quantisation if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

QED as a Classical Field Theory could mean a couple of different things. "Classical" means that all observables commute with each other, but it doesn't necessarily mean that all *fields* commute with each other. Here are two things that QED as a Classical Field Theory might mean:

1. It could mean a superclassical field theory in which the components $\psi_k$ of the spinor field $\psi$ are elements of a grassmann algebra (like in the integrand of a path integral in the quantum version of QED), but in that case the energy density is grassmann-valued instead of real-valued, so "positive" is undefined. In that context, the appropriate replacement for the positive-energy condition is reflection positivity, but that's only defined in the context of the path integral, so it doesn't really apply to classical QED.
2. On the other hand, if we take the components $\psi_k$ of the spinor field $\psi$ to be ordinary complex numbers, then the energy density is real-valued, so in this case the question makes sense — and the answer is no. The energy density doesn't have a lower bound even if we omit the coupling to the gauge field, because the kinetic term $\bar\psi(-i\gamma^k\partial_k+m)\psi$ itself doesn't have a lower bound.

So the question is undefined in version 1, and the answer is no in version 2, even if we omit the coupling to the gauge field. Here are two proofs of that statement about version 2:

- Consider the mass term, which in the usual representation is $\bar\psi\psi\equiv\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\psi$. The Dirac matrix $\gamma^0$ has eigenvalues $\pm 1$, and the quantity $\psi^\dagger(x)\psi(x)$ is manifestly nonnegative, so by considering a configuration of $\psi$ involving only negative eigenvalues of $\gamma^0$, we can make the energy density as negative as we want, with no limit, by taking the components of $\psi$ to have arbitrarily large magnitudes.
- Consider the derivative term $-i\bar\psi\gamma^k\partial_k\psi=-i\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^k\partial_k\psi$. For a plane wave, this becomes $\psi^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^k p_k\psi$. The matrix $\gamma^0\gamma^k p_k$ has eigenvalues $\pm |p|$, so we can again make the energy density as negative as we want, even if we keep $\psi^\dagger(x)\psi(x)$ fixed, just by taking $|p|$ to be arbitrarily large.

These observations are related to the reason we take the components of a spinor field to be anticommuting operators in the quantum version of QED (which leads to the spin-statistics theorem), which in turn is related to why theorists often take the components to be grassmann-valued to define what they call the "classical" version of the model, the one I called version 1.

Comment: The problem is a negative energy density arising from the sign of the momentum would be ill-defined, since it would depend on our choice of coordinates. Could you check your last bullet point?

Comment: @Joeseph123  You're right. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

In classical (c-number) theory, it depends on the variant of EM theory, not on presence of sources.

In a theory that works only with single electromagnetic field, such as the macroscopic EM theory or Lorentz microscopic theory with single EM field, EM field energy density can be defined generally based on energy interpretation of the "mathematical" Poynting theorem, which is valid whether sources are present or not:

$$
w = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 E^2 + \frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2.
$$

The interaction terms in Lagrangian/Hamiltonian like $-\rho \varphi + \mathbf j\cdot \mathbf A$, while they can be negative, are not part of EM field energy in the usual sense.

If you are asking whether total Hamiltonian including matter and interaction with matter can be negative, yes it can, because potentials $\varphi, \mathbf A$ can have arbitrarily negative value.

On the other hand, in a theory of point particles, such as the Coulomb/Newton theory of point masses with gravity or electrostatic interaction, or Frenkel's relativistic theory of charged particles, potential energy cannot be defined using Poynting's theorem (it breaks down mathematically at the point particles) but this is not a big problem, because energy can still be defined using particles' positions(in electrostatics) or individual fields in general. Then EM energy of the system can be negative.

But it is not usual for *total energy* to be negative because usually the EM interaction energy is much lower than sum of rest energies of the particles $mc^2$. Total energy of the system being negative would mean negative mass, a very strange concept.

For example, in electrostatics, Coulomb energy of a set of charges, which can be negative, can be expressed as integral of a density that is a function of individual particle fields $\mathbf E_i$:

$$
W = \frac{1}{2}\sum_i \sum_k' K\frac{q_i q_k}{r_{ik}} = \int \sum_i \sum_k'  \mathbf E_i \cdot \mathbf E_k~ d^3\mathbf x.
$$

This can be generalized (in Frenkel's theory) to the general relativistic case, and similar magnetic terms appear.

In the simplest case of two particles of opposite sign, the electromagnetic energy as defined above is negative. Hypothetically, the particles can be so close that magnitude of $W$ is higher than total rest mass of the particles and then total energy of the system is negative. But such a system has very strange behaviour (negative mass) and AFAIK hasn't been observed.

Comment: Assuming K is $\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}$ I just computed the distance required for an electron and positron to have an interaction energy that cancels their own rest mass, and it is in the order of 10^-8 m, which is well within norms of current experiment. I am just surprised that there are no experiments which have investigated this "negative mass"-like behavior.

Comment: The distance is rather around 1.4e-15 m.

Comment: Oh sorry, I accidentally took the square root, I am getting around 1e-15 m as well, there goes experiment... As a side note, would this negative interaction energy pop up in the energy-momentum tensor of GR, as negative energies are forbidden usually?

Comment: Maybe such approachment of electron and positron does happen in current experiments when the positronium decays. But it is fast and instead of observing "negative mass pair" this quickly disappears and we can only see resulting X-ray radiation.

Comment: Negative EM interaction energy has to affect energy-momentum tensor, because it affects inertial mass of bodies and thus their rest energy. It is known that hydrogen molecule mass is less than sum of rest masses of two protons and two electrons. So this defect is present, it can be accounted in the matter part or the EM part of the total energy-momentum tensor, but it has to be accounted for.